# Tank Auth forgot password does't work

Tags: codeigniter, tankauth

I use CodeIgniter + Tank Auth. Only the code http://localhost/XXXXXXXX/auth/forgot_password doesn't work.
The result always is:
"Your activation key is incorrect or expired. Please check your email again and follow the instructions."

The registration and activation are all right.

Comment: It's really hard to tell without any code. Maybe the token doesn't get saved to the database. And for the future, choose tags that have > 0 followers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some likely problems:

- Cookies are not being set correctly. Check your cookie settings, and do a test to make sure you can set and read cookies. (this may be invalid if cookies are not used for the reset)
- The reset password key is expired or wasn't set correctly. Check the database to see if hte value is correct before following the link, and check your `$config['forgot_password_expire']` in Tank Auth.
- You may be linking to the wrong URL in your email.
  This doesn't look right:

  `http://localhost/XXXXXXXX/auth/forgot_password`

  It should be something like:

  `http://localhost/auth/forgot_password/XXXXXXXX`

Not to discourage you from using Tank Auth, but having used it I can recommend trying [Ion_Auth](https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth) if you are still in the early stages. I believe it's used in [PyroCMS](http://pyrocms.com/) as well if that adds any credit.

Comment: I had some trouble getting ion_auth confiure as a hmvc module but tank_auth was flawless. Although , I am still stuck with the same email problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the XXXXXXXX in your URL is indicating that you have an extra URI segment before /auth/, you should change this:

```
function reset_password()
{
    $user_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $new_pass_key = $this->uri->segment(4);
```

to this:

```
function reset_password()
{
    $user_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $new_pass_key = $this->uri->segment(5);
```

Note the different numbers in $this->uri->segment(). With an extra segment before /auth/, your user id and activation code will be passed as parameters in the 4th and 5th segment (rather than the 3rd and 4th that Tank Auth assumes).

Answer (score 1):

it could be the time stamp in your database
in user model function "can_reset_password"
uses a UNIX_TIMESTAMP(new_password_requested)

you could echo  $user_id and  $new_pass_key if they are correct then the problem is with time comparison.
to fix the the url to always get the last two segments

```
$break =$this->uri->total_segments();
$new_pass_key= $this->uri->segment($break);
$user_id= $this->uri->segment($break-1);
```

for the time stamp try this for the function reset_password in users model

```
function reset_password($user_id, $new_pass, $new_pass_key, $expire_period = 900)
{
    $this->load->helper('date');
    $this->db->set('password', $new_pass);
    $this->db->set('new_password_key', NULL);
    $this->db->set('new_password_requested', NULL);
    $this->db->where('id', $user_id);
    $this->db->where('new_password_key', $new_pass_key);
    $this->db->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(new_password_requested) >=',mysql_to_unix( time() - $expire_period));

    $this->db->update($this->table_name);
    return $this->db->affected_rows() > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the main index.php, you have to define a time zone. Example:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
```

this will ensure that the following check has all the dates with the same time zone

```
$this->db->where('UNIX_TIMESTAMP(new_password_requested) >', time() - $expire_period);
```